# Canvas performance in Android

Tags: android, canvas

I am making a 2d game with Canvas in Android.
I have read the documentation of Canvas and I find out that we can create a class that extends View class, like this:

```
Class MyDraw extends View{
}
```

and use it as setContentView() in another class, like this:

```
class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(new MyDraw());
}
```

So my question is: What is the difference between upper code and use MyDraw class as an object without setContentView(new MyDraw()), like this:

```
class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home));

    MyDraw myDraw = new MyDraw(context);

    myDraw.draw()

}
```

Which one is better performance?
And when we should use which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance will be the same here, but there is a very important difference.

If you want to show your canvas, then you need to get it into the content view, so either as the top level view or as a child of it. But in your two examples, only the first one would be shown.

Comment: of course i want to show the canvas. i mean in second example i need a Bitmap and ImageView too to show the canvas. but as u said Performance will be the same... so thx <3

Answer (score 0):

Game engine will be better for performance :)

But, If you want to make it by youself consider using at least `SurfaceView` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView because It provides async drawing to Canvas.

Or you may want to draw it using OpenGL via `GLSurfaceView`, but this is completely different story